# Why is my splash screen being cut off in my Ionic app using Capacitor and Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor

I have followed the [Splash Screens and Icons](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons) tutorial, but for some reason, my splash screen is being cut off.

My icons and splash screen are the correct sizes, but I am still experiencing this problem.

Please see the issue below:

[image: Image being cut off in splash screen]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your logo in the middle of the splash screen is too big. Minimize the size and it should show properly.